# Simple Threading in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-multithreading

In Python2 I was using this simple way to run a `Thread` an passing parameters via args:

```
import threading


class FuncThread(threading.Thread):
    '''
        it worked fine in Python2
    '''
    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        self._target = target
        self._args = args
        print( self._args )
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self, *args):
      print( self._args )
      self._target(*self._args)

def testThreading(say=''):
  print("I'm a thread %s" % say)

t = FuncThread(testThreading, 'hi')
t.start()
```

Now in Python3 this does not work anymore, and I'm getting

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "main.py", line 11, in run
    self._target(*self._args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

because in the `run` override the `self._args` are null. If I use the new syntax in Python3 it is

```
# this works fine in Python3
threading.Thread(target=testThreading, args=('Hello Thread!',)).start()
```

that works ok, so how to correctly override the `run` method?

Comment: It looks like `self._target` is `None`.

Comment: @quamrana yes because something changed in the underlying threading library in Python3. Adding a working version but without my class.

Comment: got ya. The `__init__` before any other sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base `threading.Thread` class uses `self._target` and `self._args` for its own purposes. Because you are calling the super `__init__` without arguments, those are being set to `None` in the parent constructor. To fix this, simply remove your `__init__` use keyword args when creating the instance, and let the default behavior do the job for you:

```
import threading

class FuncThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self, *args):
      print( self._args )
      self._target(*self._args)

def testThreading(say=''):
  print("I'm a thread %s" % say)

t = FuncThread(target=testThreading, args=('hi',))
t.start()
```

If you want to keep your original constructor signature, then call the parent `__init__` with the `target` and `args` arguments, in which case you don't need to set them explicitly yourself:

```
import threading

class FuncThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        super().__init__(target=target, args=args)
    def run(self, *args):
      print( self._args )
      self._target(*self._args)

def testThreading(say=''):
  print("I'm a thread %s" % say)

t = FuncThread(testThreading, 'hi')
t.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it as follows:

```
import threading


class FuncThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, target, *args):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self._target = target
      self._args = args
      print( self._args )

    def run(self, *args):
      print( self._args )
      self._target(*self._args)

def testThreading(say=''):
  print("I'm a thread %s" % say)

t = FuncThread(testThreading, 'hi')
t.start()
```

It happened to me before, to init parent class before any attempt on the child, in this case `FuncThread` ends up overriden.

Answer (score 1):

This is a work-around for Python3:

```
class FuncThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        self._xtarget = target
        self._args = args
        print( self._args )
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self, *args):
      print( self._args )
      self._xtarget(*self._args)
```